# URL not working with One-Time-Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

I'm trying to build a login system where the user - after sign up - needs to click on a link an an activation email. I create the token in a method:

```
def get_context_data(
        self, request, user, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = dict()
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if request.is_secure():
        protocol = 'https'
    else:
        protocol = 'http'
    token = token_generator.make_token(user)
    uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(
        force_bytes(user.pk))
    context.update({
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'protocol': protocol,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
        'token': token,
        'uid': uid,
        'user': user,
    })
    return context
```

The problem here is that the generated token looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/activate/b&#39;NjA&#39;/4t8-9fad2c2dc78ecf8a1228/
```

The URL is not working because  `urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.ok))`
gennerates some weired character combinations that dont work in the url. I get the following error.

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/activate/b&

As you can see, the url is cut off after the #&.
How can I encode the `user.pk` in a way that will work in the url?

Answer (score 0):

should anyone encouter the same issue. The problem is an update to python 2.0

this fixes it:
[Django 2, python 3.4 cannot decode urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814228/django-2-python-3-4-cannot-decode-urlsafe-base64-decodeuidb64)